# isolate in SMLofNJ.Cont

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, continuation-passing

I was reading about *continuations* in Standard ML ([SMLofNJ.Cont](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/SMLofNJ/pages/cont.html)). I understood what **callcc** and **throw** does, but could not understand **[isolate](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/SMLofNJ/pages/cont.html)**. The documentation says

> Discard all live data from the calling context (except what is reachable from f or x), then call f(x), then exit. This may use much less memory then something like f(x) before exit().

However this does not make any sense to me. I just wanted to know what this function does, with some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLton does a better job of [explaining an implementation](http://mlton.org/MLtonContIsolateImplementation) of `isolate` using `callcc` and `throw`:

> ```
> val isolate: ('a -> unit) -> 'a t =
>   fn (f: 'a -> unit) =>
>   callcc
>   (fn k1 =>
>    let
>       val x = callcc (fn k2 => throw (k1, k2))
>       val _ = (f x ; Exit.topLevelSuffix ())
>               handle exn => MLtonExn.topLevelHandler exn
>    in
>       raise Fail "MLton.Cont.isolate: return from (wrapped) func"
>    end)
> ```
>
> We use the standard nested callcc trick to return a continuation that is ready to receive an argument, execute the isolated function, and exit the program. *[...]*

The page continues to explain how to achieve the same effect with less space leaking.

[MLton's `CONT` signature](http://mlton.org/MLtonCont) has a different documentation line than [SML/NJ's `CONT` signature](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/SMLofNJ/pages/cont.html):

> - `isolate f` creates a continuation that evaluates `f` in an empty context.
>
>   This is a constant time operation, and yields a constant size stack.